# Converting 2D array to 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D array in a format of (image, ID) , where some images have the same ID. For example:

```
data_2d = [(image1, 1) , (image2, 2),(image3, 2) , image(4, 2) , (image5,3), (image6,3)]
```

Now my goal is to convert this to a 3D array using their id numbers. To be more clear:

```
data_3d = [[(image1, 1) ] , [(image2, 2),(image3, 2) , image(4, 2)] , [(image5,3), (image6,3)]]
```

Is there a way to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary (or a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)) to group the tuples by id, and then convert the dictionary's values to a list:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data_2d = [('image1', 1), ('image2', 2), ('image3', 2), ('image4', 2), ('image5', 3), ('image6', 3)]

groups = defaultdict(list)
for e in data_2d:
    groups[e[1]].append(e)

data_3d = list(groups.values())
print(data_3d)
```

**Output**

```
[[('image1', 1)], [('image2', 2), ('image3', 2), ('image4', 2)], [('image5', 3), ('image6', 3)]]
```

Note that I change your variable names to strings to make the code runable.

Comment: This code does the job, I get an array with the shape of (213,). Meaning I have 213 IDs, and when I want to get the shape of each IDs using for i in data_3d: print(i.shape), I get the following error: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'. However, when I use for i in data_3d: print(i[0].shape) I get the shape of each image, for example (541, 720, 3) , etc. how can i fix this?

Comment: Each element of data_3d is a list, so it doesn't have a shape. What exactly are you trying to fix?

Comment: Sorry, I found my mistake. it was a typo. You're answer completely fixed my problem.